# ddot and hline problem

Tags: equations, mathtools

I am new to latex. Readability of the below equation is not good enough because of \hline and \ddot how may I fix it?

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq2} \underbrace{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\ddot{x_{cp}} \\
\hline
\ddot{\psi}
\end{array}
\right]
}_{\dot{x} _{4\times 1}}

\end{equation}
```

Comment: Are you sure about `\ddot{x_{cp}}` instead of `\ddot{x}_{\mathrm{cp}}`? The accent is usually placed above the variable, not taking into account subscripts. Using `\mathrm` depends on the nature of the subscript: if it is “textual” it should be upright, otherwise it would be interpreted as the product of *c* by *p*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to The TeX.SE. This code, could be a good compromise for you, starting from your code? However exists others best solutions IMHO.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq2} \arraycolsep=0.7pt\def\arraystretch{1.3}\underbrace{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\ddot{x}_{cp} \\
\hline
\ddot{\psi}
\end{array}
\right]
}_{\dot{x} _{4\times 1}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more correct solution could be this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\underbrace{\Biggl[\frac{\ddot{x}_{cp}}{\ddot{\psi}}\Biggr]}_{\dot{x}_{4\times 1}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply use the `\frac` command?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\underbrace{%
\left[\frac{\ddot{x_{cp}}}
{\ddot{\psi}}\right]}_{\dot{x} _{4\times 1}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are right!!! Thanks for helping.